# 'ValueError: The truth value of an array..' only appears when list comprehension is defined in a function

Tags: python

I apologise if this is a simple problem, I just haven't been able to understand why I keep getting the error

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I want to take an array and decompose it into a list of tuples where one element of the tuple is the index and the other is the value. My code is as follows

```
tuples = []

for index, value in np.ndenumerate(array_):

    tuples.append((index, value)) # Decompose into list of tuples
```

Once I have this list, I want to create another list of only those tuples whose modulus squared is less than a given value t. So, using a list comprehension I did

```
M = [item for item in tuples if abs(item[1])**2 < t]
```

This works perfectly fine. There are no issues in the construction of M. However, I really want to do this list comprehension inside a function with other operations. So, I did

```
def iteration(t, N, data):

    ...

    tmp_data = [item for item in data if abs(item[1])**2 < t]

    ...

    return tmp_data
```

However, now when I run the function iteration(t, N, tuples), I automatically get the ValueError raised on the tmp_data/list comprehension line. Can someone please explain why this is happening?

**EDIT**

The full code is thus

```
# Initialisation for array

N        = len(array_[0])*len(array_[1])
var      = np.var(array_)
t        = np.sqrt(2*var*np.log(N))

Z = []

for index, value in np.ndenumerate(array_):

    Z.append((index, value))

# Main loop

def iteration(t, N, data):

    tmp_noise = N # Save old N 

    tmp_data = [item for item in data if abs(item[1])**2 < t]
    tmp_N    = len(tmp_data)

    tmp_var = np.var(tmp_data)
    tmp_t   = np.sqrt(2*tmp_var*np.log(tmp_N))

    if tmp_noise != tmp_N:

        return iteration(tmp_t, tmp_N, tmp_data)

    return tmp_data
```

which you can use

```
array_ = np.random.rand(10,10)
```

to see what is happening.

Comment: On which line does the `ValueError` occur? If it's on the `if condition` line, what is the condition?

Comment: @LarsH It runs on the tmp_data/list comprehension line. I'm not sure why I added in the information about it being recursive considering that isn't where the error lies. I'll edit the post now.

Comment: What is `tmp_t`? How do you define it?

Comment: @DYZ tmp_t is a variable that is generated _after_ the list comprehension (the list comprehension is where the ValueError is being raised). I've removed the information about it now because it isn't needed for my actual question. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Yes, but _how_ is it generated? What is its datatype? (It is passed to the next call to `iteration`, so its value is important.)

Comment: @DYZ It's a floating point number. It's generated by taking the product of the length of tmp_data and the variance of tmp_data.

Comment: Are you sure it is not an array? Please include the code that shows how it is initialized.

Comment: @DYZ t = np.sqrt(2*np.var(array)*np.log(N)), where N is the number of array elements. I am 100% sure it is not an array, I just looked at its type, its a float.64

Comment: Looks like you are asking a totally different question now and you function is not recursive anymore. Are you still getting the same error message? We need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The way your question is written, it is not debuggable

Comment: @DYZ I provided the full code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tmp_t` is a two-element array. (You can see for yourself by executing the first call to `iteration` by hand, one line at a time.) When you call `iteration` again, `t` is not a float anymore; you compare a number (`abs(...)`) to an array, which raises the original error.

As far as I understand the logic of your program, you should change `tmp_var = np.var(tmp_data)` to `tmp_var = np.var(tmp_data)[1]`.

Comment: You're absolutely right, when I changed the format of the working code to what it is now, I overlooked the fact that my list was now of tuples. Thanks for your help.